# How do you remove whitespace in an Erlang string that has been assigned to a variable?

Tags: parsing, file-io, erlang

I am reading in data in the following format:

```
{ok,Volts} = file:open("voltage1.dat",read).
```

In the 'voltage.dat' file there is a single value which is converted into
the string

`"  9.9944639227844667e-001\n"`. This should be assigned to the `Volts` variable.

In order to use the string_to_float function later I need to strip away the spaces
and remove the \n delimiter.

I have explored using `string:strip`, `string:substr` and `re:replace` library functions.

I am using the variable Volts as the input string when I try each of these, e.g:

```
string:substr(Volts,3,18).
```

This does not work. I think it is because of the way that I am 
inputting the `Volts` variable.

Can anyone put me right?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Can you show a more complete code example?

Comment: Note also that when you remove blanks from a string you will be creating a **new** string and the original string will be left unchanged. Also you cannot change the value of a variable so you will have to bind a new variable to your stripped string.

Comment: @EmilVikström - The complete (non-working) code example was: `{ok,Volts} = file:open("voltage1.dat",read).` followed by `string:substr(Volts,3,18).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ok,Volts} = file:open("voltage1.dat",read).
```

will just open the file; Volts is a file descriptor, not the file's contents. In order to read the file you can use functions from the [io module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html). Besides reading the whole file and then interpreting you can use [fread/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fread-3):

```
1> {ok, V} = file:open("voltage.dat",read).
{ok,<0.34.0>}
2> io:fread(V,'',"~f").
{ok,[0.9994463922784467]}
```

If you don't want/can do that (maybe your file has a more complex format) remember that string are lists, therefore you can use `filter/2` and other list functions

Comment: Also useful in this context: `> io_lib:fread("~f", , "9.9944639227844667e-001\n").`

Comment: Thanks, I used the following to assign the input to a new variable: `{ok,[New_variable]} = io:fread(V,'',"~f").`

Answer (score 0):

If you control the in[ut file format you can use file:consult/1 which will read in the terms directly.